# Maven JAR modules, include dependencies in release?

Tags: java, maven, jar, module, architecture

I'm working on a Java monolith to split it into several reusable modules.

I'm starting to figure out there might be some issues with the dependency tree.

To explain my issues, let's imagine a simple project which include 4 dependencies :

```
 Proj
    ProjA
    ProjB
    ProjC
    ProjD
```

Imagine one of my main project dependency - ProjA - requires one of the main project dependency - ProjD- .

```
 ProjA
    ProjD
    ProjF
```

What are the best practices to prevent duplicated classes in the classpath and other dependency issues ?

Should you include the dependencies in your JAR modules and try to minimize them hard by design ? In this case, rewrite my sub-modules to make this case not happen.

Or should you build your JAR modules without dependencies and only include them in the parent "root" project ?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Are you building a jar or a war? Why do you want to duplicate classes? Multi-module projects can have dependencies from one module to another (in the pom.xml)

Comment: Each sub module should represent som related functionality or perhaps represent a layer within the app.  For example, ProjA is the persistence layter, so ProjB, ProjC, and ProjD depend on ProjA.  So it's okay to have dependencies, but NOT cyclic dependencies.  Once the modules are set up maven should complain if somebody tries to introduce a cyclic dependency.  if there is a well defined package structure then duplicate class names **in the same package** should not happen. Duplicate class names in different packages suggest duplicate code and/or poor class naming.

Comment: It's not about cyclic dependency. Just duplicated classes dependencies. Imagine 2 dependencies including as a dependency Hibernate with potentially different version. How do you resolve this issue ?

Comment: If the app is currently monolithic then I don't see how what you're describing is possible.  The top level project can define the dependency version to be used by all sub modules.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you call "modules". My modules are just standard Java JAR library dependencies that comes from my monolith. I'm not using <parent> tag or anything like that. Just including these dependencies in the <dependencies> tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Cycles :**

Maven will highlight if there are cycles in the dependency tree. You will have to refactor the modules if you see cycles.

**Build order :**

Maven will decide the build order of all modules considering which module depends on other module. So, the order of modules you specify in parent pom doesn't matter.

**Comman third party libs :**

If you have any third party dependency that is shared among different modules, best way is to keep that dependency in parent project's pom.

Comment: From my understanding, that's if your modules are not split across several projects. If your module is shared by several project, it becomes a standard dependency. What if this dependency has dependencies (3rd party or not) that conflict with other modules ? Do you include them in the JAR ?

Comment: Yes. You should include them in your module because you want your module ready for use. When your module is being used by other projects, they should take care of whether to accept your module's transitive dependencies or not. We follow this rule for any third party open source frameworks in which there are higher chances of libraries collision.

Comment: I respect standards but that's very annoying in my case. Most modules and projects do have standard apache.commons and / or hibernate and / or jackson dependencies. Which means they can't be shared according to this standard. Wouldn't it be okay to build both a JAR without dependencies + an "über-JAR" with all dependencies and include the most advantageous JAR depending on the circumstances of the project importing it ?